# Trouble with loop calculations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

I was trying to do loop calculation. I have done chapter 6 and 7 of Peskin and Schroeder which deals with one loop correction to electron vertex function and vacuum polarization. But I don't feel very confident. I think that there are major gaps in my understanding.
Can anybody suggest some better resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to do loop calculation. I have done chapter 6 and 7 of Peskin and Schroeder... Can anybody suggest some better resources?

- One thing that may help is to reconsider the problem at finite temperature. I found this helpful since you get to see how the vacuum bubbles contribute to the partition function instead of just ignoring them (well, not really *ignoring* since they factor and cancel in many calculations, but it is nice to see the cancelation more explicitly). To this end, I would recommend the book by **Kapusta: "Finite-temperature field theory"**
- Another thing that may be helpful is to read QFT books in other subject areas (I tend to thing of Peskin and Schroeder high-energy particle theory oriented). To this end, you could check out some books on QFT in condensed matter physics such as: **Mahan: "Many-particle Physics;"** and **Abrikosov, Gorkov, and Dzyaloshinskii: "Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Physics."**
- Finally, if you are taking a course, you may want to check the syllabus to see if there are other recommended textbooks besides Peskin and Schroeder. Failing that, ask your professor what additional textbooks they would recommend.